# Trigonometry sin return negative

Tags: python, c, trigonometry

I made this code in Python

```
def hitsin(a):
    a = a*57.3
    return math.sin(a)
```

so whenever i put hitsin(x) the x converted to radian. I confuse when I put hitsin(90) the answer is not 1 or any number near 1, but negative (it was -0.9971392129043587). Am I doing it wrong?

p.s: I also try to write the same kind of code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float degree;
    float result;

    degree = 90;
    degree = degree*57.3;
    result  = cos(result);

    printf("%f",result);

    return 1;
}
```

But the answer is same.

sincerely yours
Giri

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should divide by `180/pi`, not multiply.  In Python, you can also use `math.radians()` for the conversion from degree to radians:

```
def hitsin(a):
    return math.sin(math.radians(a))
hitsin(90)
# 1.0
```

Furthermore, I doubt the C code gives the same result as the Python code, because it uses `cos()` instead of `sin()`.

Comment: Your answer has the same timestamp as mine - a dead heat.

Comment: `math.radians` has a pretty confusing name (why not `degtorad` or something similar that tells *what*-to-radians?!) so I would actually find writing the conversion factor yourself much more readable and self-documenting.

Comment: @R..: When I encountered `radians()` for the first time, I immediately knew what it did.  There isn't much choice *what* to convert to radians :)

Comment: Back when I wrote game code that worked with angles, I used units of π/128. Degrees are probably just as good in modern code that's using floating point, but as a mathematician I find it pretty odd that that function is treating degrees as the implicit unit..

Answer (score 6):

You need to divide by 57.3 (or some better approximation to 180/π), not multiply.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a unit conversion error:

To convert degrees to radians:

```
radians = (2 * pi * degrees) / 360
```

Which gives:

```
radians = degrees / 57.295... = degrees * 0.01745...
```

Comment: or `math.radians(degrees)` which is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The factor 57.29… converts from radians to degrees. However you need to do the exact opposite.

```
def degree_to_radian(x):
    from math import pi
    return x*pi/180

# pi/180 = 0.0174…

def degsin(x):
    from math import sin
    return sin(degree_to_radian(x))
```